# Cannot get jwt tokens sent from frontend in backend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm a newbie at Django and simplejwt and I have encountered a problem. Tokens are being sent to me from our Angular frontend by the names of "app_token" and "access_token" but I cannot find a way to retrieve them in my Django code. I have tried names like "HTTP_APP_TOKEN" and "HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN" and even had our frontend team rename the tokens but that didn't help as well. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *by the names of "app_token" and "access_token"*  - what does this mean? Do you mean field names in the request header? Ususally the token is sent in the "Authorization" header, e.g. Authorization Bearer <jwt>

Comment: That's right, they're named that way in my request header. I don't know much about this issue and the more I search the more confused I get so I don't really know the reason why they chose not to send it in Authorization header. The tokens do have the "Bearer <jwt>" format tho.

Comment: Are you using djangorestframwork-simplejwt?

Comment: Yes, David. I'm using djangorestframework-simplejwt.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputiation to add a comment yet, I want to make sure if you are using a **nginx** to forward your request. If yes, maybe follow answer will be helpful, otherwise, please comment me to delete.

**By default Nginx ignores the headers with underscore.** This can explain why your header property like `app_token`, `access_token` cannot pass to the backend.

1> You could set `underscores_in_headers` on in your [nginx config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers).

2> Using header preperty without underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can get token from request; For example you protect views with IsAuthenticated permissions and you have a method name get in views

```
def get(self, request):
    token = request.headers['Authorization']
    # other code
```

If you have used simplejwt then token is passed like `Bearer access_token` from frontend as headers